# check current date is which day of month(Finding which day of month?) in javascript

Tags: javascript

check that what day of month my current date is, will this solution work in that case as well? Like today 11/21/2016 is Third Monday of month.

Comment: yes, you can say this as well, like i can always get what current day is, but i want to identify that whether it is first, second, third... occurrence in current month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://jsfiddle.net/z6zum0hk/

```
 var date = new Date();
 var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
 var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
 var weeksPassed = Math.floor(date.getDate()/7); 
 if(date.getDay() >= firstDay.getDay()){
   alert((weeksPassed+1) + " " + days[date.getDay()] + " of month" )
 }else{
   alert((weeksPassed) + " "+ days[date.getDay()] + " of month" )
 }
```

explanation :

Date will give you the date of month so by that you can find how many weeks have passed
Day will give you day 0 to 6 sun to sat
so then if your current day is before the start month of day then current day is no of weeks passed day else its weeks passed + 1 day

Comment: At a small cost in readabilty, you can lose the "if" clause by making date.getDate() into (date.getDate()+6) and never having to add one to weeksPassed.

Comment: Thanks , this is what i wanted, now problem is that i want to get date on 3rd monday of next month, i am sorry but i am new to JS and dont have idea of these calculations, can you help?

Comment: what does 2nd alert shows? Date of nth day of next month? if so it is wrong

Comment: like for current day 2016 11, 23,  fiddle out put shows 4th Fri of month and 2nd alert shows the date same as today , its slightly confusing

Comment: @SameenJavid I have put a date 2016,10,25 in fiddle you need to today change it to just new Date() for current date see this https://jsfiddle.net/z6zum0hk/7/

Comment: one more quick question , why i am getting next date as 23-0-1970, how can i get valid next month and year? like 23-12-2016

Comment: @SameenJavid https://jsfiddle.net/z6zum0hk/12/ there was a bracket problem

Comment: there is a small issue in code. it is not calculating correct date after 2nd month, like 26-12-2016 is 4th Monday of December but it is showing it as 3rd Monday. I have tried debugging your code but couldn't get exact point of error. please recheck